# Can't get pointer back to zero

Tags: c++

I can't get the pointer back to zero so i can go through the data again after the echo.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open ("scores.txt" , ifstream::in);

    int ch = infile.get();
    string lastname;
    char gender= ' ';
    string collegetype;
    float score=0;
    float scoreMALE=0;
    float scoreFEMALE=0;
    int countMALE=0;
    int countFEMALE=0;

    while ( !infile.eof())
    {

          cout << (char) ch;
           ch = infile.get();
    }

    infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    while ( !infile.eof())
    {
    infile>>lastname>>gender>>collegetype>>score;
    if(gender == 'm')
          {
                scoreMALE = scoreMALE + score;
                     countMALE++;   
          }         

    else if (gender == 'f')
          {
                  scoreFEMALE = score;
                  countFEMALE++;
          }
    }

  cout<<"\n\n\n The total Female Scores is"<<countFEMALE<<"\n\n\n The total of the male scores is"<<countMALE; // Checking to see if file works


  infile.close();

  cout<<"Press <Enter> to Exit";
   cin.ignore();
   cin.get();      
   return 0;                   
}
```

here's the input file:

Bailey           M CC 68
Harrison         F CC 71
Grant            M UN 75
Peterson         F UN 69
Hsu              M UN 79
Bowles           M CC 75
Anderson         F UN 64
Nguyen           F CC 68
Sharp            F CC 75
Jones            M UN 75
McMillan         F UN 80
Gabriel          F UN 62

Comment: Your code does not have any pointers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you asking about moving the file pointer back to the start of the file after reading through it once? If so, you have that code already (you do it once).

Comment: Add `infile.clear();` before the second round.

Comment: I added the infile.clear() and it still wont read the file the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the infile.clear() above the infile.seekg(0,ios::beg), causes the code to iterate through the second loop here (as [Kerreck-SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) suggested) .

The reason your scores would still be 0 after doing this is due to the character comparison used being of the incorrect case. E.g. 'f' and 'm' instead of the 'F' and 'M' in your input file.

Comment: I just realized that less than a minute ago that the Characters were lower case. Thanks for your help, learning C++ can be a pain in the butt!